# Highchart's yAxis label's 'overflow' property not updated on chart redraw( called when legend item is clicked or toggled)

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
```

Example for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw36U/.

Ideally yAxis label should be justified after chart is redrawn on legend item click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set useHTML (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.useHTML) as true and define CSS styles for custom label (use formatter for define it http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter)

```
 labels:{
                useHTML:true,
                width:120,
                formatter:function(){
                    return '<div class="label">' + this.value + '</div>';
                }
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw36U/1/